# How can i get source element which call ajax request in "ajaxComplete" handler

Tags: jquery

I am developing a ajax based website in this website i have make history of all requested page through ajax call. after a hour search i got a Histroy.js lib to manage my state.
but my problem is to get element which call ajax and update only a block of div.
so i want something like this.

```
<a href="a.php" class="ajax" data-block-to-update="a_block"> 
<div id="a_block">
```

when user click on this link a ajax call should go and after getting response i have to update a div which id is "a_block"

here is my script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var History = window.History;
        var State = History.getState();
        var $log = $('#log');

        History.pushState({state:'1',rand:Math.random(),content:$('#main').html(),block:'main'}, 'index', State.url);
        //History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);

        $('.ajax').live('click',function(){
        var gen_url = $(this).attr('href');
        var bl = $(this).attr('data-block');
            $.ajax({
                url: gen_url,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log($(this));
                  $('#'+bl).html(data);
                  History.pushState({state:gen_url,rand:Math.random(),content:data,block:bl}, gen_url, gen_url);
                }
                  });
        return false;
        });

        $.ajaxSetup({

              });

        $(document).bind("ajaxComplete", function(e, xhr, settings){
                            // need to get element which make ajax request
            console.log(xhr);
            //var obj = $(e.target.activeElement);
            //alert(obj.attr('data-block'));

        });

        History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {
            var State = History.getState();
            if(State.data.content!="" && State.data.block!="")
            {
                //History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
                $('#'+State.data.block).html(State.data.content);
            }
            else
                return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

How to get element which call ajax request in "ajaxComplete" event handler?

Comment: Could I suggest you read the last jQuery documentation?
You're using depreciated function like .live('click') which have been replaced by .click() which makes it already a lot easier to read.

Still working on a correct answer…

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i will apply it.
yes i am still searching for my question answers
please help me

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly i can think of two ways of solving this, one more elegant then the other.

The first one would be to have a php file that captures all the data and since you are using jQuery, i would use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/.

What was a little diffuse from your question was what information would you like to gather, if you say would like href data, i would write something like this to collect all elements:

```
$('a[href]');
```

You can add an event listener using bind:
http://api.jquery.com/bind/

```
$('a[href]').bind('click', function()
{
    saveHistory();
    document.location = this.href;
});
```

And set links 'onclick' to return false, in that case you wouldn't be transferred to a site when you clicked the link, the transfer could be handled by the javascript.

However, i have never done this before, this was just my quick thoughts on the subject.
Hope it can be to some help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your problem is passing the object to an other function.

If so, you need to declare a variable outside the first function and use the function to save the data in that variable. All variables which are initialized in a function are deleted at the end of it.

In your case I would say that there is only a little change to your code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ajax_element;
    // Do all you need as before…

    $('.ajax').live('click',function(){
    ajax_element = $(this);
    var gen_url = $(this).attr('href');
    var bl = $(this).attr('data-block');
        $.ajax({
            url: gen_url,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log($(this));
              $('#'+bl).html(data);
              History.pushState({state:gen_url,rand:Math.random(),content:data,block:bl}, gen_url, gen_url);
            }
              });
    return false;
    });
    // Etc…

    $(document).bind("ajaxComplete", function(e, xhr, settings){
        // need to get element which make ajax request ->
        // the element you want to catch here is: ajax_element
        console.log(xhr);
        //var obj = $(e.target.activeElement);
        //alert(obj.attr('data-block'));

    });
})
</script>
```

You still have to be carful that your second function doesn't trigger before the ajax call is done. I would suggest making a function that you can call from within your ajax success function to be sure it won't be triggered to early (in the case that it has to be triggered after).

Also, when using a link I would suggest to block the normal event propagation from the start, some browsers will propagate the action before doing what is asked by the JS.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.
but click event is bind with the help of "cakephp js link" so i can't add this "ajax_element = $(this);" in it's handler.
look at this : 
www.gumbodigital.com/gumbocake

if you have any other suggestion please help me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I've slightly edited my code to correct my answer. I don't really understand why you can't do what I suggest in the handler. It looks like a jQuery script and it should work fine.